# list date created and file name for all files in subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory

I am currently using the following line in my batch file to retrieve a list of pdf files in my subdirectory that contain the word "complete" in the title.

```
dir /b /s *COMPLETE*.PDF >Q:\"Personal Folders"\Advertising\"Data Updates"\ePrint\test.csv
```

Is there a way that I can change this to append the date created to the beginning of each file so that I can sort them by date in excel? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I append the date created to the beginning of each file name?

Use the following batch file.

**GetFileCreateDate.cmd:**

```
@echo off 
setlocal
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /s "*COMPLETE*.PDF"') do (
  for /f "tokens=1,2" %%g in ( 'dir "%%f" /tc ^| findstr /C: "%%~nxf"') do (
    echo %%g,%%h,"%%f"
    )
  )>>Q:\"Personal Folders"\Advertising\"Data Updates"\ePrint\test.csv
endlocal
```

Notes:

- Output lines will have the format:

  ```
  create_date,create_time,"filename"
  ```

  Where `filename` is the absolute name of the file
- Modify `echo %%g,%%h,"%%f"` to suit the format you want in your csv file.

  `%%g` is the create_date, `%%h` is the create_time and `%%f` is the absolute filename.

Example output (writing to just "test.csv"):

```
F:\test>dir /b /s "*COMPLETE*.PDF"
F:\test\1complete1.pdf
F:\test\2complete2.pdf
F:\test\complete1.pdf
F:\test\complete2(s).pdf

F:\test>GetFileCreateDate.cmd

F:\test>type test.csv
26/08/2016,21:28,"F:\test\1complete1.pdf"
26/08/2016,21:28,"F:\test\2complete2.pdf"
26/08/2016,21:28,"F:\test\complete1.pdf"
26/08/2016,21:28,"F:\test\complete2(s).pdf"
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, but when I run this nothing happens. No text.csv file is created. If I manually create a test.csv file, nothing is written to it.

Comment: @user3221816 You are doing something wrong. See updated answer for test output.

Comment: Oh, I don't doubt that I am doing something wrong. When I try to run GetFileCreateDate.cmd from the cmd prompt, I get a message "File Not Found" even though it exists in the directory.

Comment: @user3221816 Are the files hidden by any chance?

Comment: Can you try replacing `Q:\"Personal Folders"\Advertising\"Data Updates"\ePrint\test.csv` with just `test.csv`? Also replace `echo off` with `rem echo off`.

Comment: @user3221816 What was the problem?

Comment: Your `find /v "(s)"` could skip _valid_ file names e.g. `COMPLETE(s).PDF`. I'd use  `find ":"`

Comment: In fact, I don't know how `find ":"` or `findstr "^[0-9]` depends on national (locale) date and time format settings (both work for me)…

Comment: @JosefZ I just `findstr` on the filename now. That matches the correct line of output regardless of any date/time settings :)

Comment: `findstr /C:"%%~nxf"` to avoid fake matches in `dir` command recapitulation for _such obscure_ filenames like `File COMPLETE.PDF`, `0 COMPLETE.PDF` etc. Also consider adding `/I` switch (case-insensitive search). Sorry if I look like pure fault-finder now…

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks for the correction. I don't mind "nitpicking" if it improves the anser :)

Comment: The space after the /C: causes an error, removing it resolves

Answer (score 0):

Next code snippet lists *last written* date & time and file paths:

```
>"Q:\Personal Folders\Advertising\Data Updates\ePrint\test.csv" (
    for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b /s *COMPLETE*.PDF') do echo %%~tG "%%~G"
)
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~tG` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`>`, special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, but I only get an empty .csv file when I run this.

Comment: This answer returns the modified date not the creation date (which the question asked for).

Comment: @DavidPostill I know (please read _last written_ date & time in opening). Weird that the OP gets an empty .csv file (as well as he complains it in your answer).